# How can I get MAMP to tell me what went wrong with php code?

Tags: php, macos, mamp

Whenever I have an error in my php code, MAMP just returns a 500 error. Is there anyway I can get MAMP to tell me what went wrong like parsing errors and stuff?

Comment: I figured it out i just had to change line 277 of php conf file to turn on error reporting.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Just as you reported, you must have `display_errors` set to `on`.  This can be done either by changing the conf file or by using .htaccess like so:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag display_errors on
</IfModule>
```

Additionally, you can do this with `ini_set()` like so:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

One last thing, you can also check `/Applications/MAMP/logs` which has three different error log files.

Try opening terminal and run this command:

```
tail -f /Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log
```

When you want to stop "following" (the `-f` switch) the log file, just type **control+C**.

Comment: In newer version of MAMP the default filename may be "phperror.log":

Answer (score 11):

#### You can also access **MAMP** errors using the Mac **"Console" app** to read the **`php_error.log`** file.

I find this easiest to access by using spotlight and typing in "error.log".

[image]

*( it won't find it if you type "php_error.log", you must type "error.log" )*

#### It looks like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### 2022 update:

If we talk about usual MAMP (not PRO version), my research showed that there's no way to enable displaying of PHP errors using GUI. However, all the old approaches with configuration files mentioned in [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8642515/9345547) and [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581460/why-mamp-doesnt-display-errors) [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233932/php-doesnt-display-errors-on-mamp) still work. But be careful with config names since they have been changing over some versions.

For MAMP PRO users: You can easily enable outputting of PHP errors using GUI:

1. Switch to `Expert view` at the top left corner: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/815Ft.png)
2. Click on the PHP language: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MypX6.png)
3. And then check the option `to screen` of the `Log errors` property: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEZJ5.png)
4. Hit `Save` and restart the servers when MAMP asks you to restart or not.

You're done. PHP now should output error message in the place where error occured.

Also, if you prefer configuring everything by hand, the option with configuration files works here as well.

At the time of writing this answer, the actual version of MAMP (and PRO) was 6.6.2.