# Why MAMP doesn't display errors?

Tags: php, error-handling, mamp

OK this is getting very frustrating. MAMP used to display errors but then stopped. I decided to do a fresh install of it as I couldn't figure it out. I check my PHP version, running 5.4.4 and go to that folder and change the php.ini to this:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

Still no errors showing. I go through all the folders and change all php.ini files, just in case. Nothing. I fix the forced error and dump out `phpinfo()`, check the error section and display_errors is Off. What the hell.

I place `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` at the start of the PHP file and `phpinfo()` again. Local value is now On, master is still Off. Force a PHP error, and still get Server Error not PHP error.

Anybody have any insight? I have a bug somewhere in some code and cannot find it, would love for PHP to just tell me.

Comment: MAMP or MAMP Pro is not anevironmnet to use for develope or debug web applications. Turn to wampserver64 or xampp to do serous web development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For newer versions of MAMP, the config file is stored in `Appliations/MAMP/bin/php/[php version]/conf`.

Andrew Nagy pointed me in the right direction with his answer, but it wasn't quite correct for my installation of MAMP. Why they're different, I can't tell, but here we are.

If anyone is stuck, the easiest thing to do is to just `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` in the index file of the application and look for the loaded `php.ini` directory.

Comment: This is exactly what worked for me. ```NOTE:``` You must restart the server after changing the ```php.ini``` file for it to take effect

Answer (score 79):

MAMP sets up a few different `php.ini` files for the server, the client etc. Check in your `phpinfo()` which `php.ini` actually is read. Looks like you're editing the wrong one.

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea. MAMP was reading from /MAMP/bin/php/5.4.4, I was editing /MAMP/conf/php/5.4.4. What a pain!

Comment: That also bugged me a month ago or so... ;-)

Comment: and don't forget to restart apache server after changes. :)

Answer (score 37):

There are two `php.ini` files on MAMP. You should change both `php.ini` files.

1. `Applications/MAMP/bin/php/'php version you are using(php5.5.10)'/conf/php.ini`
2. `Applications/MAMP/conf/php/'php version you are using(php5.5.10)'/conf/php.ini`

Then change:

```
display_errors = Off
```

to:

```
display_errors = On
```

Comment: Why change two? 1st option seems fine.

Comment: I think I changed the first one and then restarted the service and it worked fine

Comment: Mine has two: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php[v#]/conf/php.ini` and `/Applications/MAMP/conf/php[v#]/php.ini`... why are there two?! Why do we need to modify both? Regardless, both have `display_errors = Off`, however, when I go to MAMP > File > Open Template > PHP > v#, it opens a php[v#].ini file that shows `display_errors = MAMP_display_errors_MAMP`... where's that value stored?! If I look at phpinfo(), it shows `display_errors` 'On' for both Local and Master Value. Yet caught Exception shows nothing. This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 20):

If you're using MAMP PRO, you have to enable Error handling (PHP) in the UI interface, in the "PHP" tab under the "Languages" section of the sidebar: Check What to log & Log errors: to screen which should contain at least two the main options: 'Display startup errors' and set output 'To: Display'.

`Display startup errors` option is equivalent to `display_startup_errors` (in PHP) and `To: Display` to `display_errors`.

See below:

[image: MAMP PRO - Error handling]

Comment: How can I open this UI interface?

Comment: in the SIDEBAR LANGUAGES PHP TAB : Check What to log & Log errors: to screen

Answer (score 7):

Change the setting in your `php.ini` file. The file is located in `MAMP > conf > php5 > php.ini`

Look for `display_errors = Off` and change to `display_errors = On`

After that you need to restart your Apache and MySQL servers for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 3):

MAMP PRO users can visit the PHP tab in UI and make sure Log Errors: to screen is checked: [screencast](http://www.screencast.com/t/EhMpl3aU)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a 2018 update to this problem.
First, I'm having the same trouble and found this thread. I used phpinfo() and found yet another location of a php.ini file. Here are the paths (I work on a Mac):

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/[php version]/conf/php.ini

/Applications/MAMP/conf/php/[php version]/php.ini
```

and ...

```
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini
```

The phpinfo() page lists two sources for the php.ini:

- **Configuration File (php.ini) Path**
  /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/[php version]/conf
- **Loaded Configuration File**    /Library/Application
  Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini

I ended up changing all three, adding `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to some pages, restarting the server (even rebooted the machine) and *still* cant get it to display any error messages.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

**** ---------------------------------------------- ****
2020 Edit
**** ---------------------------------------------- ****
The latest MAMP upgrade (v6) has changed the main web host directory. It's not in the Applications/MAMP/ directory. That's a good thing. But it required me to change where all my projects live. I had to reconfigure my IDE, Postman, Git, and some others. So, I figured this would be a perfect time to move to Docker containers.

Docker brings a whole new level of challenges but once I got familiar with it and deployed a few containers, it's been great. It feels faster when rendering in the browser and I am more confident that my projects will run as expected on the production server. Eventually our production servers will use containers, so it just makes sense for me.

Comment: What version of MAMP is this?

Comment: I've got MAMP PRO v5.1. But, I solved it by uninstalling the whole thing and reinstalling. It works again, but not sure for how long.

Comment: I always find upgrading MAMP to be a nightmare, it never remembers settings. I just don't do it now, despite it's constant protesting. I'm glad you got it working. As long as you don't upgrade, you should be golden.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MAMP version 3.2.2 then you only need to change one php.ini file:

Mac: `Applications/MAMP/conf/'(php7.0.9)'/php.ini`

Windows: `C:\MAMP\conf\PHP Version you use'(php7.0.9)'\php.ini`

I know this is an old post but MAMP keeps changing their configuration of the files so I hope this helps.

Comment: I've not used MAMP for quite a while now, so I am unsure of the configuration files, so if this is now the correct way of doing things, that's fantastic. Much easier!

Answer (score 0):

Also there is a template saved in MAMP of the `php.ini`.
Go to `File > Edit Template > PHP > Your Version`.

Answer (score 0):

On MAMP 3.2.0 and PHP 7 you'll need to target `php.ini-production` and change the value to `Production Value = On`