# display_errors remains off (php.ini)

Tags: php, mamp-pro

I'm currently running MAMP Pro on OSX 10.9.2.

I'm running PHP 5.3.6.

I've tried to set `display_errors = On` in the php.ini file but phpinfo() keeps showing it as Off. I looked for possible answers but what I found repeatedly was people mentioning there was a second `display_errors` line further down which was setting the value back to Off. This is not my case, I don't have that second line in my php.ini file.

The file I'm modifying is **/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf**.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: `phpinfo()` (SAPI mode) and `php -i` (CLI mode) will tell you exactly which .ini they're using, and where it is. make sure you're modifying the right one, and have restarted php completely (e.g. restart the webserver app) to make sure the changes take effect.

Comment: also check if you are modifying the config file used by PHP. You can find which ini file PHP is using from `phpinfo()` or `php -i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable or enable error message in MAMP Pro UI Interface. You can follow this documentation of MAMP: http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/server/php and this SO Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19951357/817365