# How do I enable error reporting in PHP (MAMP)?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, mamp

So I'm running MAMP on my Mac since I was unable to change my htdocs location to a directory on a local server (no problem to use that local server with MAMP though)

Somehow, php error reporting is disabled for me.
I used phpinfo(); to find the right ini file (which is located at "Applications ▸ MAMP ▸ bin ▸ php ▸ php5.6.10 ▸ conf" in my case) and changed **display_errors** from "off" to **"on"** (without the " " of course)

**error_reporting** is set to **E_ALL**

However, when I now run phpinfo(); again, Display errors is still turned off.

I have also tried to override those values in the php code without success.

**Apparently MAMP  overrides the modified php.ini everytime it starts. Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/16154605/2667307

Comment: Try to override them in code using: `error_reporting(-1);` and `ini_set("display_errors", "on");`

Comment: I already tried. Sorry, I have edited it in now. Thanks for your time! @Naruto

Comment: Did you restart all services after making changes?

Comment: Yes of couse I did. Restarted all services and even restarted MAMP to make sure @Fred-ii-

Comment: Looks like you're editing the wrong php.ini file

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581460/why-mamp-doesnt-display-errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you are not creating a script with `<?php phpinfo() ?>` ? by running in browser you'll see `Loaded Configuration File` This tells you which `php.ini` file PHP is using like for me it's at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

[image: Review below screenshot.]

though,

You can try to override it by doing [error_reporting(E_ALL);](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

```
// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and

```
if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Works and now Display Errors is on when using phpinfo(); Do I have to paste this on any of my php files now?

Comment: Any idea why simply editing the php.ini did not work for me?

Comment: @Noni simply editing php.ini would be best way but when you do have specific requirement you can do it.

Comment: May be you've edited wrong file i guess i'm working.

Comment: For me, `if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {ini_set('display_errors', '1');}` did the job, `error_reporting(E_ALL);` was not needed.

Comment: Of course I was using phpinfo(); to find out where my configuration is located, but editing it did not have any effect.

Comment: @Noni  Please review http://stackoverflow.com/a/16154605/2667307 and other answers helps!

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issue. Then i found in MAMP if you go to "File -> Edit Template -> PHP -> ". Edit the file there and restart MAMP.

The issue is that the files reside in two or three places in MAMP on Mac.

Comment: Does this require the PRO version? I only have the standard one. I am 100% sure I edited exactly the php.ini file that I was shown by phpinfo(); how can I have edited the wrong file then?

Comment: Then i will edit my answer. Its still good to know. Do a "find / -name php.ini" in terminal. It will find all your php.ini in your system.

Comment: Thank you @isnisn, I am new to MacOS

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
error_reporting(E_ALL) ; ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

in your PHP script to

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL) ; ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

will display the errors properly in your browser. 
As the first alternative should send the errors to your log file.

You can check the manual here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.error-reporting.php