# PHP doesn't display errors on MAMP

Tags: php, macos, apache, mamp

I'm using the basic MAMP on Mac, and PHP doesn't display errors, I already changed PHP and Apache configuration but still, can someone help me?

Comment: try including this in your script `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);` `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Have a read here and see if this help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display#21429652

Comment: @Blinkydamo Yes, I did, but it doesn't fix my problem!

Comment: @GhostWorker Doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure that you are editing the right file. MAMP usually creates several php.ini files. Call `phpinfo()` and check the path to the correct php.ini.

In your php.ini you need to set the following:

```
display_errors = on
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Don't forget to restart Apache after the changes.

Comment: Ok, I solved my own Problem, at the end of php.ini, display_errors was turned of, so it ignored the first argument

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but I can't comment yet. Its obvious and a stupid thing to do, but if anyone else has this issue there are lots of comments in the php.ini, make sure you are changing the actual variable definition and not just a comment!