# Why is simple boolean php instance function not working?

Tags: php

#### Problem

I have this `Task` class in php:

```
class Task{
public $title;
public $due_date;
public $priority;
public $course;
public $note;

function __construct($title, $due_date, $priority, $course, $note) {
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->due_date = $due_date;
    $this->priority = $priority;
    $this->course = $course;
    $this->note = $note;
}

public function is_empty(){
    return ($this->title === '' || $this->due_date === '' || $this->priority === '' || $this->course ==='' || $this->note ==='');
}
}
```

But when I try to use `is_empty()`, it doesn't work (& stops all functionality below):

```
            //If valid form elements & not a duplicate, add it to data file
            if($valid_title && $valid_note && $valid_date){
                $task = task_from_form();
                //Don't add duplicates or tasks with empty elements
                echo "work please"; //prints
                $is_empty = $task->is_empty();
                echo "$is_empty"; //doesn't print
                if(!$is_empty && !in_array($task, $tasks)){
                    //write task to file
                    write_file($filename, $task);
                    //add task to gloabl var tasks
                    $tasks[] = $task;
                }
            }
```

I'm not sure what syntax error I'm making, and I'm sure it's something stupid, so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

### Code

The `task_from_form()` function (but I know this works b/c I've used it before without calling `$task->is_empty()`):

```
//Return task from form elements
function task_from_form(){
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['note'])){     
        if($_POST['title'] !== '' && $_POST['note'] !== ''){
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $note = $_POST['note'];
            $title_trim = trim($title);
            $note_trim = trim($note);
            $title_html = htmlentities($title_trim);
            $note_html = htmlentities($note_trim);

            $due_date = $_POST['due-date'];
            $priority = $_POST['priority'];
            $course = $_POST['course'];
            $course_space = str_replace("-", " ", $course);
            
            $task = new Task($title_html, $due_date, $priority, $course_space, $note_html);
            
            return $task; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I'm not sure what syntax error..."_ - Step one when debugging, check your error log for a proper error message.

Comment: it is shown some message error?

Comment: What did you expect, whats going wrong?

Comment: It could be that the if statements in your `task_from_form()` doesn't validate to true, and therefore not returning an instance of your class, which you're trying to use later on. This: `$task->is_empty()` will break your code if the function returned null instead of a class instance

Comment: @MagnusEriksson where can I see this error log? I'm using brackets for my text editor and MAMP to see my website, which I'm viewing on Chrome

Comment: To get the errors in MAMP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641383/how-can-i-get-mamp-to-tell-me-what-went-wrong-with-php-code

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It seems that I'm getting `[23-Feb-2017 16:49:31 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function is_empty() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/p2/index.php on line 116`

Comment: Quick fix can be `if(is_object($task)){$is_empty = $task->is_empty();} else {$is_empty =true;}` instead of just `$is_empty = $task->is_empty();`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Question: is the error saying `$task` is null?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson why might task be null? is it b/c it only returns  in the if statement?

Comment: You only return the class instance if all your if statements validates to true. If any of those conditions are false, your function won't return anything, which is the same as NULL. NULL = Lack of anything.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, removed the comment :)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson mmm I see. I guess I'll add another if block to check `is_null` before using `$task`

Comment: Yes, you'll need to do that. Check the suggestion in @JustOnUnderMillions comment.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Whew, got that working finally! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MagnusEriksson & @JustOnUnderMillions comment I realized that `$task = task_from_form()` was returning `null` since the `return` statement was  nested in an `if` statement. So if the `if` statement did not evaluate to true the `task_from_form()` would return null. And then I would call the instance method `is_empty()` on a null `$task`. So I used `is_null($task)` to check for null before manipulating `$task`.

I also found out how to [find errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641383/how-can-i-get-mamp-to-tell-me-what-went-wrong-with-php-code) using MAMP! Which was honestly the main problem b/c I didn't know how to do that before so debugging was quite difficult

### Fixed code

```
                //If valid form elements & not a duplicate, add it to data file
            if($valid_title && $valid_note && $valid_date){
                $task = task_from_form();
                //Make sure task is not null
                if(!is_null($task)){
                    //Don't add duplicates
                    if(!$task->is_empty() && !in_array($task, $tasks)){
                        //write task to file
                        write_file($filename, $task);
                        //add task to gloabl var tasks
                        $tasks[] = $task;
                    }
                }
            }
```